# Tailwind layout overflow-x-hidden not working

Tags: html, layout, tailwind-css

I'm building a layout in Tailwind which contains curved borders, I've managed to create these but its causing the layout to be wider than I'd like, so causing scrolling across the layout, when it should be centered. I've tried overflow-x-hidden with no luck and can't find a way to use a ::before or ::after pseudo element in tailwind, is there a solution to this?

I've tried all-sorts, from adding a parent div with overflow-x-hidden to trying w-full or w-screen on the body... to adding before: to all the properties.... not sure what to try next...

```
 <body
    class="font-sans text-dark-blue min-h-screen w-screen relative overflow-x-hidden bg-white"
  >
    <!-- Background & Hidden Images -->

    <div
      class="block absolute -z-10 h-[2500px] w-[2500px] rounded-full bg-dark-blue -top-[1400px] left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 scale-150 shrink-0"
    ></div>
```